# Acronyms from the Expanded Universe of Star Wars

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Exploring a database of “Star Wars: Behind The Magic”,
I encountered these acronyms from the expanded Universe.
I guessed some, I may be wrong about one or two, but I don't know about the others.
One important info is that these works are prior to 1998.
These acronyms may not be official,
but I found some of them on http://starwars.wikia.com.

You may find here the data I converted for my work (JSON format, but in a variable glossary): https://behindthemagic-etiennewan.c9users.io/js/database.js

```
{
"ESB": "The Empire Strikes Back",
"TBH": "Tales of the Bounty Hunters" , 
"SWCG": "",
"SOTE": "Shadows of the Empire",
"RJ": "Return of the Jedi" ,
"CCG": "Star Wars Customizable Card Game",
"DE": "Dark Empire",
"SWVG": "",
"SWSB": "",
"TOBH": "",
"BTS": "",
"HE": "",
"HESB": "",
"DFR": "",
"EGPM": "The Essential Guide to Planets and Moons" ,
"GG4": "Galaxy Guide 4: Alien Races" ,
"SW": "Star Wars: A New Hope",
"SWR": "Star Wars: Rebellion",
"ISB": "",
"SFS": "",
"LC": "",
"DS": "",
"DA": "",
"FP": "",
"HLL": "",
"TJP": "Tales from Jabba's Palace",
"CS": "",
"ISWU": "",
"TSW": "",
"DLS": "",
"DFRSB": "",
"NR": "",
"TAB": "",
"COJ": "",
"TOJ": "",
"FNU": "",
"HSR": "",
"DESB": "",
"TMEC": "",
"MTS": "",
"JS": "", 
"GG2": "",
"DF": "",  
"COF": "",
"ROC": "",
"POT": "",
"SWWT": "", 
"GG1": "", 
"GDV": "",
"CSW": "", 
"ESBSB": "The Empire Strikes Back Sketchbook", 
"TOJDL": ""
}
```

Please help me to fill in the blanks
(and correct any errors that might be present) in the above.

Comment: SWVG - Star Wars: Video Game

Comment: DESB - Dark Empire Sourcebook / TMEC - Tales from the Mos Eisley Cantina

Comment: TOJDL - Tales of the Jedi: Dark Lords of the Sith

Comment: This should probably be a wiki answer.

Comment: Where did you "encounter" them?

Comment: In Star Wars: Behind The Magic encyclopedia, in a database file "GLOSSARY.CSV". They seem unused, but for each entry in this glossary, I've got a list of this acronyms (I suppose they indicate the appearance of the current entry in the EU)

Comment: "GG1": "Galaxy Guide 1: A New Hope",
"GG2": "Galaxy Guide 2: Yavin and Bespin",
"HSR": "Han Solo's Revenge",
"DFRSB": "Dark Force Rising Sourcebook",
"TOJ": "Tales of the Jedi",

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- BTS: *Before the Storm*
- CCG: *Star Wars Customizable Card Game*
- COF: *Champions of the Force*
- COJ: *Children of the Jedi*
- CS: *The Crystal Star*
- CSW : *Classic Star Swars (Dark Horse Comics. #10 includes the Night Beast)*
- DA: *Dark Apprentice*
- DE: *Dark Empire*
- DESB: *Dark Empire Sourcebook*
- DF  : *Dark Forces (Video Game)*
- DFR: *Dark Force Rising*
- DFRSB: *Dark Force Rising Source Book*
- DLS: *Tales of the Jedi: Dark Lords of the Sith*
- DS: *Star Wars Droids Special (Dark Horse Comics)*
- EGPM: *The Essential Guide to Planets and Moons*
- ESB: *The Empire Strikes Back*
- ESBSB : *The Empire Strikes Back Sketchbook*
- FNU: *Tales of the Jedi: Freedon Nadd Uprising*
- FP: *Farlander Papers*
- GDV: *The Glove of Darth Vader*
- GG1 : *Galaxy Guide 1: A New Hope*
- GG2: *Galaxy Guide 2: Yavin and Bespin*
- GG4: *Galaxy Guide 4: Alien Races*
- HE: *Heir to the Empire*
- HESB: *Heir to the Empire Sourcebook*
- HLL: *Han Solo Lost Legacy*
- HSR: *Han Solo's Revenge*
- ISB: *Imperial Sourcebook*
- ISWU: *The Illustrated Star Wars Universe*
- JS : *Jedi Search*
- LC: *The Last Command*
- MTS: *Movie Trilogy Sourcebook*
- NR: *The New Rebellion*
- POT: *Planet of Twilight*
- RJ: *Return of the Jedi*
- ROC: *River of Chaos (Dark Horse Comics)*
- SFS: *Strike Force Shantipole*
- SOTE: *Shadows of the Empire*
- SW: *Star Wars: A New Hope*
- SWCG: *The Essential Guide to Characters*
- SWR: *Star Wars: Rebellion*
- SWSB: *The Star Wars Sourcebook*
- SWVG: *The Essential Guide to Vehicles and Vessels*
- SWWT : *The Essential Guide to Weapons and Technology*
- TAB: *The Truce at Bakura*
- TBH : *Tales of the Bounty Hunters*
- TJP: *Tales from Jabba's Palace*
- TMEC: *Tales from Mos Eisley Cantina*
- TOBH: *Tales of the Bounty Hunters (Again)*
- TOJ: *Tales of the Jedi (Dark Horse Comic)*
- TOJDL: *Tales of the Jedi: Dark Lords of the Sith*
- TSW: *Tales of the Jedi: The Sith War*

---

Sources:

I cross-referenced the characters listed in the [database](https://behindthemagic-etiennewan.c9users.io/js/database.js) the matched each acronym, and then searched for common denominators on [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/), Amazon (For confirmation of Han Solo's Revenge as a title), a list of the [West End SW RPG books](http://www.rancorpit.com/WestEndGamesBooks.html), Comic Vine and Wikipedia to confirm both comics and other titles, and [TheForce.Net](http://www.theforce.net/).

*Tales of the Bounty Hunters* appears to be the only duplicate entry. I believe this is an error on the part of the database, not me. The biggest pieces of evidence for this are:

- There are only 3 entries containing "TOBH" for appearances
- Boba Fett is listed as in "TOBH" but not "TBH". "TBH" is clearly *Tales of the Bounty Hunters*, evidenced by the many other characters shown. If these acronyms weren't duplicates, Boba Fett would certainly have both (as one section of *ToBH* is called *The Tale of Boba Fett*)

The *Star Wars: The Essential Guide to...* acronyms aren't consistent with the titles they shorten (or among themselves, as "SWWT" doesn't have the "G" that the other 2 do), but I looked heavily into who/what they contained and it all matches the database.

Lastly, I also double-checked the OP's assumptions.

Comment: Wow! Amazing work. I was concerned about coherence too and was about to verify but you did the work. Thank you very much.

I forgot some acronyms in my question, but I will use your sources and method to identify the missing ones.

I will use these data for my project here: https://behindthemagic.github.io/#glossary/

Answer (score 3):

You may find this bibliography (from Star Wars: The New Essential Guide to Characters) to be of use in future.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very nice! I'm disappointed that it doesn't clarify issues I ran into, like *SWWT* and other *Guides* besides the few listed. It'd be really satisfying to have corroboration!